# Keyboard Inputs

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard

I'm coding a project and I've got a problem when I try getting keyboard input in a dedicated class.

So this is my Controller class :

```
Controller = function() {
// Initialisation clavier 
document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown;
document.onkeyup = this.onKeyUp;
// Touches 
this.left = false;
this.up = false;
this.down = false;
this.right = false;
}

// Touche appuyée 
Controller.prototype.onKeyDown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        this.left = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        this.up = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        this.down = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        this.right = true;
    }
}

// Touche relâchée 
Controller.prototype.onKeyUp = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        this.left = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        this.up = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        this.down = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        this.right = false;
    }
}
```

... with which I create an occurence during initialization. But when I try to get boolean state in an other class :

```
// Déplacement
Player.prototype.move = function() {

    if (controler.left) {
        this.posHorizontal -= this.speed;
    }
}
```

this isn't working ! When I display the state in the controller class it return 'true' but not in another classes. I'v got no error but only a 'false' displayed (i've tried with console.log but no way).

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

When the browser calls `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` methods, after the events happen, the `this` keyword inside the functions points to the document not to the `Controller` instance.

change the lines

```
document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown;
document.onkeyup = this.onKeyUp;
```

to

```
document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
document.onkeyup = this.onKeyUp.bind(this);
```

and it should fix the issue.